# Can I run Balloons.IO by gravityonmars?

Tags: server

I wonder if I can run [Balloons.IO](http://balloons.io/) an open source project on my Ubuntu Server?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes you can.

The project seems to use `node.js` and `redis`, both of which are available in Ubuntu repositories.

Balloons.IO's repository even has some installation docs: https://github.com/gravityonmars/Balloons.IO/blob/master/README.md